# Models with Nested Effects

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am having difficulty understanding nested effects. Suppose 20 people each are assigned to treatment groups A B C and D. Would it be correct to say that Person is nested within treatment group? So for example, for each subject within each treatment group, each subject underwent 10 trials and for each trial, his heart rate was recorded. Would a model be:

$HeartRate_{ijk} = Treatment_{i} + Subject_{j}(Treatment)_{i} + Trial_{k}(Subject_{j}) + e_{k(j(i))}$

where Subject and Trial are random effects and are nested? So there are no interaction terms in this model?

Comment: Yes. Given that a Person can only be assigned in one Group it is nested. Read some of the basic literature on the subject; for something free, quite applicable (but slightly outdated in computational terms) the book *lme4: Mixed-effects Modeling with R* is more than enough.

Comment: Then why is it here: http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/anovmix1.htm subject or trial are not treated as nested effects for the mixed model?

Comment: Are you sure they are not? I have never use `SAS` or `proc mixed` but I suspect that the line: `REPEATED trial / SUBJECT=sub TYPE=CS;` has something to do with the nesting (well the lines above don't). Actually in the current example they might even ignore the Group:Person nesting and care only about the Person:Measurement nesting. Try first a simple random effects model to get an idea about how nesting works and then go ahead and try to understand what goes on in the repeated measurements case; *Example 56.2 Repeated Measures* from the SAS 9.2 User's Guide might be of assistance (later).

Comment: It's also weird that they don't have subject as a random effect. If there are modeling dv for each subject, they would need to have subject listed as a random effect via. random subject.

Comment: Are you sure that this has nothing to do with the statement (in the example of repeated measurements in SAS I gave you just now) : "*The REPEATED statement contains no effects, taking advantage of the default assumption that the observations are ordered similarly for each subject.*" On second thought, have you read the line in the page you gave : "*We also use the repeated statement to indicate which variable indicates the different subjects (via subject=sub)*". Really get a simple example working first and then go for repeated measurements ANOVA (and read the documentation more carefully).